# Setting up a mass distribution email list from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This should be straight-forward but I somehow can't get it right. I am trying to set-up an automatic email blast from Excel. I have followed step by step the instructions from other posts here, with no success. This is a dummy example I've created, for the sake of simplicity.

[image]
I would like to:

- send emails to everybody in the list
- conditionally replace certain keywords in the body
- populate a column with the delivery status for each email (sent/failed)

My current code sends the email only to the first person in the list. I've used my personal email address for testing purposes. I wonder if sending the emails to the same address could be the issue. If anybody can provide some guidance, would be much appreciated!

```
Sub SendMail()

Dim EmailSent, EmailFailed, i As Integer
Dim StatusSent, StatusFailed As String

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


EmailSent = 0
EmailFailed = 0
StatusFailed = "failed"
StatusSent = "sent"
i = 1

Do
DoEvents

    With olMail
        .To = Cells(i, 1).Value
        .Subject = "test"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

        .HTMLBody = Cells(i, 2).Value

        If Cells(i, 3) = 1 Then
            .HTMLBody = VBA.Replace(olMail.HTMLBody, "replace_me", Cells(i, 4))
        Else
            .HTMLBody = VBA.Replace(olMail.HTMLBody, "replace_me", Cells(i, 5))
        End If

       .send

    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    olMail.send

    If Err Then
        EmailFailed = EmailFailed + 1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = StatusFailed    'change status from pending to failed
    Else
        EmailSent = EmailSent + 1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = StatusSent  'change status from pending to sent
    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop Until i = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count

If EmailSent = 0 Then
    MsgBox Prompt:="Emails could not be sent"
Else
    MsgBox Prompt:="Sent emails: " & EmailSent & vbNewLine _
    & "Failed emails: " & EmailFailed
End If

On Error GoTo 0
Set olApp = Nothing
Set olMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Do a mail merge to email in Word. It's all set up and ready to go. No code required.

Comment: This is just a small part of a bigger project, that keeps track of participant enrollment in training courses. All the implementation right now is in Excel and I would like to do it without having to leave the program.

Comment: Plus, I'm not aware that Word can send completely different email templates, based on a condition. In the real-life example, there are 4 types of pending statuses for participants (pending1, pending2 etc.). Based on this, I'd be sending different kinds of emails.  Pending1 notifies about enrolment, pending2 notifies waitlisted participants, pending3 notifies when the status of sombody changes to enrolled, and pending4 notifies when the status changes to cancelled.

Comment: Yes, Word can do that. The merge fields can process conditional logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing two crucial lines in your `Do` loop:

```
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

and at the end:

```
Set olMail = Nothing
```

Try this instead:

```
Sub SendMail()

    Dim EmailSent, EmailFailed, i As Integer
    Dim StatusSent, StatusFailed As String

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

    EmailSent = 0
    EmailFailed = 0
    StatusFailed = "failed"
    StatusSent = "sent"
    i = 1

    Do
    DoEvents
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With olMail
            .To = Cells(i, 1).Value
            .Subject = "test"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Importance = olImportanceHigh
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

            .HTMLBody = Cells(i, 2).Value

            If Cells(i, 3) = 1 Then
                .HTMLBody = VBA.Replace(olMail.HTMLBody, "replace_me", Cells(i, 4))
            Else
                .HTMLBody = VBA.Replace(olMail.HTMLBody, "replace_me", Cells(i, 5))
            End If

           .send

        End With

        On Error Resume Next
        olMail.send

        If Err Then
            EmailFailed = EmailFailed + 1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = StatusFailed    'change status from pending to failed
        Else
            EmailSent = EmailSent + 1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = StatusSent  'change status from pending to sent
        End If

        Set olMail = Nothing

        i = i + 1
    Loop Until i = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count

    If EmailSent = 0 Then
        MsgBox Prompt:="Emails could not be sent"
    Else
        MsgBox Prompt:="Sent emails: " & EmailSent & vbNewLine _
        & "Failed emails: " & EmailFailed
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```